# Word Counter plugin in textarea WordPress solution not working in jquery 1.11.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've set up my form with the code from this thread: [Counting and limiting words in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909646/counting-and-limiting-words-in-a-textarea)

However the fiddle code was written with jQuery 1.8.3 and it is working fine with that however, my wordpress site is using jquery 1.11.0 - what sort of modification do I need to make to the code for it to work with this version of jquery? Code below...

Thanks for your help.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#word_count").on('keydown', function(e) {
        var words = $.trim(this.value).length ? this.value.match(/\S+/g).length : 0;
        if (words <= 200) {
            $('#display_count').text(words);
            $('#word_left').text(200-words)
        }else{
            if (e.which !== 8) e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
 }); 
});//]]>  
</script>

  <textarea name="txtScript" id="word_count" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
Total word Count : <span id="display_count">0</span> words. Words left : <span id="word_left">200</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's not the jQuery versions that are having an impact as if I change the fiddle you referenced in this [Counting and limiting words in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909646/counting-and-limiting-words-in-a-textarea) answer found here http://jsfiddle.net/7DT5z/9/ to use jQuery 1.11.0 as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/7DT5z/21/ it still works.

I believe it is the way jQuery is included by default in wordpress, you're referencing jQuery in normal mode but it includes itself in `noConflict` mode in wordpress by default which means `$` (alias if `jQuery`) is not available and you need to user `jQuery` instead.

So your code would need to read:

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#word_count").on('keydown', function(e) {
        var words = jQuery.trim(this.value).length ? this.value.match(/\S+/g).length : 0;
        if (words <= 200) {
            jQuery('#display_count').text(words);
            jQuery('#word_left').text(200-words)
        }else{
            if (e.which !== 8) e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
 }); 
});
```

Another *easier* way of modifying code which references the short-form alias `$`
is this. - as beautifully explained and demonstrated here http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$("#word_count").on('keydown', function(e) {
        var words = $.trim(this.value).length ? this.value.match(/\S+/g).length : 0;
        if (words <= 200) {
            $('#display_count').text(words);
            $('#word_left').text(200-words)
        }else{
            if (e.which !== 8) e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    });
```