# How to limit the number of words in a div contenteditable jQuery

Tags: jquery

I found on the internet a way to limit the number of characters; which is this:

jQuery

```
var myDiv = $('#your-div-id');
myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,300))
```

I'd like to limit the number of words. I have this code but I don't know how to use it to do what I want.

jQuery

```
var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
var wordLimit = 215;
var words = primo.textContent.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,"").split(/\s/);
```

Comment: This can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17909970/2168947

Comment: @Brewal doesn't work for divs

Comment: use `.text()` instead of `val()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909970/2168947), the only thing you have to do to make it work with content editable divs is to use `text()` instead of `val()` :

```
var wordsLimit = 20;

$("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {
    var words = $(this).text().match(/\S+/g).length;
    if (words > wordsLimit) {
        // Split the string on first 200 words and rejoin on spaces
        var trimmed = $(this).text().split(/\s+/, wordsLimit).join(" ");
        // Add a space at the end to keep new typing making new words
        $(this).text(trimmed + " ");
    }
    else {
        $('#display_count').text(words);
        $('#word_left').text(wordsLimit-words);
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3mvngav3/)

Comment: bit trickier in browsers that create new block element for each new line. Other answer is for textarea which doesn't have child elements

Comment: I this case when I write more than 20 words, on the 21 it starts to delete the last one and writes the 21th a the beggining... doesn't work

Comment: This is another issue. Maybe you want to [keep the cursor at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity/3866442#3866442) of your div ? Maybe you want to remove the "contenteditable" attribute ? But IMO this is answering your question

Answer (score 0):

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="text-div"></div>

var textDiv = document.getElementById("text-div");
if (textDiv.textContent.length < 1) {
    document.querySelector("#alert").textContent = "You must enter a text.";

    return;
  }
  console.log(textDiv.textContent.length);
```