# How to create a text area word counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, word-count

I created a couple inputs that feed into a JavaScript command to create custom sentences. Whatever the user inputs or selects is added to a sentence framework. When the user selects submit, the sentence is created in a textarea. How can I add a feature to my app that counts the words within the textarea? I simply want a small text box to the bottom right of the text area that states how many words are in the text area.

Thanks so much for your help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 <title>Hi</title>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">

 <style type="text/css">
  table,td,th {margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}
  .display {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
  p {text-align: center;}
  textarea {display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;}
  .chosen-select {width:200px}
 </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function sentence() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";// reset
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "block";

    if (document.getElementById("z1").value == "") {
      alert("Year, Make, and Model are needed");
      document.getElementById("z1").focus();
    }

    else {
      const input1 = document.getElementById("z1").value;

            var input3 = $('#z3').val();
            console.log(input3);

            var input3Formatted = "";
            if(input3.length==1){
              // Only one value...
              input3Formatted = input3[0];
            }
            if(input3.length==2){
              // Two values... Just add and "and"
              input3Formatted = input3[0]+" and "+input3[1];
            }
            if(input3.length>2){
              // more than 2 values...
              for(i=0;i<input3.length-1;i++){
                input3Formatted += input3[i]+", ";
              }
              input3Formatted += "and "+input3[input3.length-1];
            }



            const input5 = "It has minor curb rash on the "+input3Formatted+"."
            const input7 = document.getElementById("z5").value;




      document.getElementById("s1").value =
        "This is my " +input1+ ". It is in good condition.The vehicle's rims have curb rash. "+input5+" The "+input1+"'s color is "+input7+"."

    }
  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
      disable_search_threshold: 4
    })
});
</script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z1" placeholder="Year, Make, Model" name="name" maxlength="100" >
        </td>
        <td>
            <select data-placeholder="Minor Curb Rash" name="minorrash" multiple class="chosen-select" id="z3">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="front left rim">Front Left Rim</option>
              <option value="back left rim">Back Left Rim</option>
              <option value="front right rim">Front Right Rim</option>
              <option value="back right rim">Back Right Rim</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="z5" placeholder="Color" name="name" maxlength="100">
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="sentence()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="s1"></textarea>
    <br>

    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="reset()" id="r1">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting and limiting words in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909646/counting-and-limiting-words-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 2):

i don t know if this is what are you trying, this is what I understood of your question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var nameValidationInput = document.getElementById('s1');//here you search in your text area al the words
  function useValue() {
  var NameValue = nameValidationInput.value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = NameValue.split(" ").length // here you count the word separated by a space
  }
</script>
<br>
<textarea rows="1" cols="5" id="demo"></textarea>// just to show the count in the text area
<br>
```

in this way the function will count each word separated for a space (if you want something more detailed if will be a much more dificult)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest way to do it is to store all the text from the textarea in an array (separated by white spaces). You can use `.split` to achieve that. Once done, then simply get the length of the array. It'll return the world count. 
Try this.

```
var splitData = textarea.value.split(" ");
var wordCount = splitData.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

I will leave a another version of what was sugested. Using length is not enough because it will count every whitespace as a word, and at the begining it will count 1 word even when its empty. I sugest using trim() and filter to prevent those bugs, for example:

```
wordsArr = text.trim().split(" ")
wordsArr.filter(word => word !== "").length
```