# How to limit my text area field to 1000 words in my html form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello i have an about me field on a profile page i created, but noticed that i cant copy and paste words from other documents even when my max length is set to 1000 words, When i copy and paste in the text area , it takes in 50 words or so. My about length in the database is set 2000.Below is what i have in my form. Any help offered is deeply appreciated

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="about">About Me</label>
<textarea name="about" rows="3" maxlength="1000" class="form-control" id="about"></textarea>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spV88.png)

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909646/counting-and-limiting-words-in-a-textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The maxlength attribute defines the maximum number of characters (as UTF-16 code units) the user can enter into an  or .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength

I created a simple example when the maximum number of words is 5:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('textArea');
const textContent = [];
let maxWords = 5;

function separateWords(text, e){
 let words = text.split(" ");
  
 if (words.length >= maxWords + 1) {
   input.setAttribute('maxLength',words.join(" ").length - 1);
    return words.join(" ").trim();
  } else {
  return words.join(" ");
  }
};

input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
console.log(separateWords(input.value));
});
```

```html
<div>
<p>
Type something (max 5 words):
</p>
<textarea id="textArea" value=""></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but my form prevents me from entering more than 50 words. Any solution?

Comment: I am writing one possible solution for you, just a moment.

Comment: @AbrahamAugustusNortey I edited my post with a simple example. Maybe this is not the most efficient way, but I think it can do the job.

Comment: sorry for the late response,  tried it today but some somehow does not work on my page , also causes some other fields on the form to stop working..

Comment: @AbrahamAugustusNortey For the issue related to other inputs being blocked, you can select the specific input by using .getElementById(). I edited my code so now only the element with id "textArea" will have this behavior.
Now, do you have the repo link so I cant take a look?

Comment: No please I don't,  but will try it and let you know the outcome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The tag `maxlength` defines the number of max `characters` and not max words.

Perhaps your text is more than 1000 characters so it does not work